# How to convert google map into black and white using google IOS sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-maps

Is there any way to convert the google map in black and white mode using google IOS sdk ?

Answer (score 1):

Custom styling is not yet supported in iOS SDK. 
The current version is v1.92. Custom styling is supported on v3.

You can use JavaScript Stylers by rendering the map in an UIWebView. 
Example of JavaScript Styler for Black & White (JSON Format):

```
[
  {
 "stylers": [
   {"saturation": -100}]}
]
```

Two alternatives would be [MBXMapKit](https://www.mapbox.com/mbxmapkit/) and [MapKit](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/).